# Fitting equation inside a column

Tags: numbering, columns, revtex, fit

I am using twocolumn revtex mode, and for my matrix to fit inside the column I used this 'trick'

```
\begin{equation}
\resizebox{1.\hsize}{!}{
\bordermatrix{~ & \tau & r & \theta & \varphi \cr
              & h_{\tau\tau}=\bigo(r^2) & h_{\tau\tau}=\bigo(r^2) & h_{\tau\tau}=\bigo(r^2) & h_{\tau\tau}=\bigo(r^2) &\cr
              & h_{\tau\tau}=\bigo(r^2) & h_{\tau\tau}=\bigo(r^2) & h_{\tau\tau}=\bigo(r^2) & h_{\tau\tau}=\bigo(r^2) & \cr
              & h_{\tau\tau}=\bigo(r^2) & h_{\tau\tau}=\bigo(r^2) & h_{\tau\tau}=\bigo(r^2) & h_{\tau\tau}=\bigo(r^2) \cr
              & h_{\tau\tau}=\bigo(r^2) & h_{\tau\tau}=\bigo(r^2) & h_{\tau\tau}=\bigo(r^2) & h_{\tau\tau}=\bigo(r^2) \cr}}
\end{equation}
```

Which is fine, since this fits my matrix inside the column, but I don't like what it does to the numbering:

[image]

Is there a way to have one line of space between the matrix and the numbering? Or do I need to load some dreaded code inside for it to work? I looked at some examples here, but I would like a minimal code adjustment (like `\resizebox` for example)...

Comment: I think this is the usual way to put an equation tag when there is no enough space. `amsmath` package has the `\raisetag` command to move the tag. By the way, all elements of the matrix are equal, is this a fake matrix or it is what you really want to typesset?

Comment: Fake matrix :D Don't worry XD So I could try with \raisetag... Is there a \lowertag command? :D

Comment: @dingo_d -- as with many commands that accept values, `\raisetag` with a negative argument will do the opposite, namely lower the tag.

Comment: why have the first two rows got an extra `&` that is making the right hand bracket be misplaced? If you removed then and changed the scale to .8\textwidth the number would probably fit to the side

Comment: extra &? If I remove the & at the beginning I loose the matrix parenthesis... :\

Comment: The `&` at the _end_ of the first two rows are spurious which is why the spacing of the brackets is wrong with much more space before `)` than after `(`. I would get rid of the spurious space before `)` the scale to (say) .8\columnwidth  so that the equation number fits on same line

Comment: @dingo_d --- If you are still interested in answers to this question, please edit it so that it includes a complete example code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Oh, this is an old question, I think I figured it out in the end (or expanded it so that it was across the entire page).